# Подскажите, где ошибка в проверке совпадения логина с БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Постоянно пишет что Логин занят:
Вот сама проверка с БД (работает все корректно передает false или true)

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'POST')
{   
    include "../conect/connection.php";
    include "../functions/functions.php";

    $login = clear_string($_POST['reg_login']);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT login FROM reg_user WHERE login = '".$login."' ");

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo 'false';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'true'; 
    }
}
```

но все равно пишет что логин занят, даже если обработчик сообщил что его в БД нет

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form_reg').validate({
    // правила для проверки
    rules: {
      "reg_login": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 15,
        remote: {
          type: 'post',
          url: "reg/check_login.php"
        }
      },
      "reg_pass": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 7,
        maxlength: 15
      },
      "reg_surname": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 15
      },
      "reg_name": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 15
      },
      "reg_patronymic": {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3,
        maxlength: 25
      },
      "reg_email": {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      "reg_phone": {
        required: true
      },
      "reg_address": {
        required: true
      },
      "reg_captcha": {
        required: true,
        remote: {
          type: "post",
          url: "reg/check_captcha.php"

        }

      }
    },

    // выводимые сообщения при нарушении соответствующих правил
    messages: {
      "reg_login": {
        required: "Укажите Логин!",
        minlength: "От 5 до 15 символов!",
        maxlength: "От 5 до 15 символов!",
        remote: "Логин занят!"
      },
      "reg_pass": {
        required: "Укажите Пароль!",
        minlength: "От 7 до 15 символов!",
        maxlength: "От 7 до 15 символов!"
      },
      "reg_surname": {
        required: "Укажите вашу Фамилию!",
        minlength: "От 3 до 20 символов!",
        maxlength: "От 3 до 20 символов!"
      },
      "reg_name": {
        required: "Укажите ваше Имя!",
        minlength: "От 3 до 15 символов!",
        maxlength: "От 3 до 15 символов!"
      },
      "reg_patronymic": {
        required: "Укажите ваше Отчество!",
        minlength: "От 3 до 25 символов!",
        maxlength: "От 3 до 25 символов!"
      },
      "reg_email": {
        required: "Укажите свой E-mail",
        email: "Не корректный E-mail"
      },
      "reg_phone": {
        required: "Укажите номер телефона!"
      },
      "reg_address": {
        required: "Необходимо указать адрес доставки!"
      },
      "reg_captcha": {
        required: "Введите код с картинки!",
        remote: "Не верный код проверки!"
      }
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(data) {

          if (data == 'true') {
            $("#block-form-registration").fadeOut(300, function() {

              $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_good").fadeIn(400).html("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!");
              $("#form_submit").hide();

            });

          } else {
            $("#reg_message").addClass("reg_message_error").fadeIn(400).html(data);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Вот подключение к БД

```
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db ("goodvac");
mysql_set_charset("utf8");

if(!$connection || !$db)
{
    exit(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Приведите код ошибки и наверное код 'connection.php', а еще структуру БД и записи в ней, и что передаете. 
p.s. желательно использовать для таких вещей *prepared statement*, вместо танца с конкатенацией строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первой строчке:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == 'POST')
```

Метод запроса содержится в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. 
Я этот вариант тоже пробовал, но с ним вообще не работает проверка по БД